# Send data to a Php Script with Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have to send some parameters from my Android application to a Php script, for a database insert.
I tried this script on Eclipse and it works fine.
But when I try to run it on Android it crashes.

```java
public static void Insert(){
        try {
            // open a connection to the site
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.105/JavaInsert.php");
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            // activate the output
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
            // send your parameters to your site
            ps.print("&email=random@gmail.com");
            //ps.print("&Company=Company");               
            //ps.print("&Shares=Shares");
            //ps.print("&Date=Date");

            con.getInputStream();
            ps.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("Db error 1");
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("Db error 1");
        }
    }
```

There are these errors in the LogCat section

```
07-28 14:28:07.259 20554-20554/com.example.ivan.rocketsocialstudioapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ivan.rocketsocialstudioapp, PID: 20554
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6663)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6635)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:794)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7593)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6663) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6635) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:794) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7593) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1523)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:231)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:145)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:141)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
        at com.example.ivan.rocketsocialstudioapp.MainActivity.Insert(MainActivity.java:72)
        at com.example.ivan.rocketsocialstudioapp.MainActivity.send(MainActivity.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6663) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6635) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:794) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7593) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
07-28 14:28:07.284 20554-20554/com.example.ivan.rocketsocialstudioapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20554 SIG: 9
```

The Php script works with Eclipse.
I've also already added the android Network and Internet Permissions

Comment: Please share the logcat. BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. method names should start with lower case character

Comment: is the ip addrss 192.168.1.105 reachable by your phone?

Comment: @Jens Yes it is reachable

Answer (score 1):

its because you cant run network operation on main thread it will cause the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` which you have

try networking libraries or do the operation on a AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Runnable Thread or AsyncTask to run network operations.

Check out my example below

```
 private void login() {

    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    try {
        //Populate the request parameters
        request.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        request.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        //Log.v("test", request.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, login_url, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        //Check if user got logged in successfully

                        if (response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 0) {
                            session.loginUser(username, response.getString(KEY_FULL_NAME));
                            loadDashboard();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    response.getString(KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    //Display error message whenever an error occurs
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```